# Write the difference of 2 density operators in terms of a spectral decomposition

Tags: textbook-and-exercises, density-matrix, nielsen-and-chuang

An exercise question (9.7) from Quantum computation and Quantum Information by Michael E. Nielson and Isaac L. Chuang says that I can write the difference of any 2 arbitrary density operators $\rho,\sigma$ as a spectral decomposition:
$$
\rho - \sigma = U D U^\dagger
$$
But for this to be true, isn't it necessary that the density matrices must commute?
From what I understand, I will need an orthonormal basis in which both will be diagonalizable. Based on the Simultaneous diagonalizable theorem this is only the case when $\rho$ and $\sigma$ commute.

What am I missing?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If the density matrices commute then there exists a **joint** spectral decomposition of both $\rho$ and $\sigma$. I.e. there exists a unitary $U$ and diagonal positive semidefinite matrices $D_{\rho}$ and $D_{\sigma}$ such that
$$
\rho = U D_{\rho} U^\dagger \qquad \text{and} \qquad \sigma = U D_{\sigma} U^\dagger.
$$
Note that here you are diagonalizing two different matrices using the same unitary.

The statement you're actually concerned with is different. You're asking whether a **single** matrix $X := \rho - \sigma$ can be diagonalized. But this is true as $X$ is Hermitian and so the spectral theorem applies.